# C++/CX unable to use string variable in class

Tags: c++-cx

I'm currently writing a class in C++/CX and I'm trying to create some string variables for the class. However for some off reason it is showing this error(See below):

[image]

Could anyone please spot out why its doing this as its really annoying and ive tried a few things! Please see the code for the class below:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

ref class Plane
{

public:
    Plane();
    double getSpeed();
    std::string getPlaneId();
    double getFuelLevel();
    std::string getLastStatus();
    int getLastContactTime();
    bool saveData();
    std::string latitude;
    std::string longitude;
private:
    double speed;
    std::string planeId;
    double fuelLevel;
    std::string lastStatus;
    int lastContactTime;
};
```

Comment: Try removing `ref` if you're writing *C++*.

Comment: This is not C++. And the error looks pretty self-explanatory to me.

Comment: @zenith ahhh the joys of programming eh! thanks it worked!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit im new to c++! and it is c++ :P

Comment: @codingbenn: And I am telling you that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing C++, remove the `ref` and start using a C++ compiler.

If you're writing C++/CX ([an extension to C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CX)), you can't use `std::string` inside a managed (ref) class, because `std::string` is a non-managed type and managed classes can't have members of non-managed class types. That's what the error message is saying.

Answer (score 0):

One of the rules of C++/CX is you can not have non reference classes that are publicly exposed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh969551.aspx

If you need to publicly expose a string then you can use `Platform::String^` instead of `std::string` (it's easy to convert between the two).

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

ref class Plane
{
public:
    Plane();
    double getSpeed();
    Platform::String^ getPlaneId();
    double getFuelLevel();
    Platform::String^ getLastStatus();
    int getLastContactTime();
    bool saveData();
    Platform::String^ latitude;
    Platform::String^ longitude;
private:
    double speed;
    std::string planeId;
    double fuelLevel;
    std::string lastStatus;
    int lastContactTime;
};
```

If you only need to access the `std::string` from non C++/CX code then you can use the `internal` scope.

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

ref class Plane
{
public:
    Plane();

    // it's okay to have simple types in the public signature
    double getSpeed();
    double getFuelLevel();
    int getLastContactTime();
    bool saveData();
internal:
    std::string getPlaneId();
    std::string getLastStatus();
    std::string latitude;
    std::string longitude;
private:
    double speed;
    std::string planeId;
    double fuelLevel;
    std::string lastStatus;
    int lastContactTime;
};
```